# What does this symbol mean?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am studying a book on functional analysis and came to a definition that started like this:

> Let $M$ be a set and $F: M \hookleftarrow$ a function (...)

My only question is: what does the $\hookleftarrow$ mean?

Comment: an injective function?

Answer (score 1):

The little curly bit means the function is injective; it is otherwise the same as an ordinary arrow. More generally it means the morphism is a monomorphism in the relevant category.

Comment: Just to expand, the sentence quoted seems to indicate that $F$ is a monomorphism of $M$ into itself.